# Is there any way I can store images uploaded from angular front in the angular directory path of assets/logos?

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have a page where I can upload an image and currently it gets stored in the database through the API call. Instead is there any way I can store it in the local directory of my angular directory, for eg: assets/logos?

Comment: But why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: Why dont you get it from the database then? Anyway you can, just use your API to store the image in the directory you want to instead of the database. E.g.: with a nodeJs API you can use `fs.writeFile()`